# CUDA porting of a struct with internal random function

Tags: c++, random, cuda, porting

I have to port on a GPU a structure that use extensively the random numbers.   Everything could be ported without a lot of problems but the random generator function is the only thing that it's called extensively in all the function of this class.
I though I could simply reimplement it as a internal device function of the class itself.
Below I put a toy model of what I need (take in consideration that the class with which I am working is more complicated).
I need also that each call of the function "rand" give a different random number (even in the same object).
Here the toy model, however it produce wrong results.  Could anyone help me to correct it please?

```
#include <cuda.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <curand_kernel.h>
using namespace std;

struct test{

float value;

curandState B;

void __device__ rand(){value=curand_uniform(&B);}
void __device__ foo(){rand();}
};

__global__ void setup_kernel(curandState *state)
{
const int id=blockIdx.x;
curand_init(id, id, 0, &state[id]);
}

__global__ void fill_mat(struct test *anobj, curandState *state)
{
 const int Idx=blockIdx.x;
 curandState localState = state[Idx];
 anobj[Idx].B=localState;
 anobj[Idx].foo();
}

int main()
{
int num=10;
curandState *devStates;
cudaMalloc(  (void **)&devStates, num*sizeof(curandState) );

struct test *results = (struct test*)malloc(num*sizeof(struct test));
struct test *to_device;
cudaMalloc ( (void **)&to_device, num*sizeof(to_device));

setup_kernel<<<num, 1>>>(devStates);

fill_mat<<<num,1>>>(to_device, devStates);

cudaMemcpy(results,to_device,num*sizeof(struct test),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

for(int i=0;i<num;i++)
 cout<<results[i].value<<endl; 
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain in more detail what "wrong results" you get?

Comment: @harrism at the beginning I was calling anobj[Idx].rand(), I added foo() later and I didn't check if it compile, now I can't check I don't have nvcc on this computer (but I will check in few hours).   However I expect that if you call  anobj[Idx].rand() from the kernel then "value" should get a random number. Instead I get a series of zeros when I print the output in the last for cycle.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for  the great (and complete) example. After building it I found two issues.

When you cudaMalloc to_device you want to allocate num*sizeof(struct test) bytes.

I'm assuming you might want to invoke fill_mat more than once, or you might have other kernels and you want them to get different numbers each time.  If so, at the end of fill_mat (or other kernels that make a copy of curandState), you need to copy your local state back to curandState.  This is because curand advances the state each time you generate a number.

Lastly (and this is not necessarily a bug) I see you are using thread id as both the seed and the sequence in the call to curand_init.  This is OK, but there is some (extremely unlikely) risk that curand's seed scrambling algorithm would land you in a part of the sequence that overlaps with that of some other thread.  curand_init uses a scrambled version of  the seed to generate an initial state, and then applies a skipahead of 2**67 times the sequence. Generally, the intent is that all threads would use the same seed, to guarantee that each thread is 2**67 away from the previous, within the sequence.

PaulS.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Actually i found that without a call of cudaMemcpy "host to device" the code don't give the right results.    For the rest you are completely right.     Now I am moving to the next issue, when "value" is an array of size "N" (but you allocate it at the host!) and you want to fill it in the kernel.